# Cocoapods use_frameworks! only in debug builds

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

Doing a standard React Native build. react-native-firebase requires `use_frameworks!`, and react-native-flipper doesn't work with `use_frameworks!`.

In debug mode, I want to use Flipper, but I don't care about RN Firebase.

In release mode, I want to use RN Firebase, but don't care about Flipper.

```
pod_folder = Pathname.new(__FILE__).dirname.realpath

require File.join(File.dirname(`cd #{pod_folder} && node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`cd #{pod_folder} && node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`cd #{pod_folder} && node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'MyApp' do
  use_expo_modules!

  # Only use use_frameworks! in production


  # Required for RN Firebase
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :production => production,
    # to disable hermes on iOS, change `true` to `flags[:hermes_enabled]` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    
    # Flipper doesn't work when use_frameworks! is enabled,
    # and this is required for react-native-firebase. 
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug"], { 'Flipper' => '0.157.0' }),
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # truncated for space
end
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Though RN firebase does show to use `use_frameworks!`, but I think it is not important, I didn't did any thorough research but I have used RN firebase without `use_frameworks!` and works fine in both debug as well as release mode

Comment: The easiest way might be to add a new target without ```use_frameworks!```